# Separate logs for every endpoint in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, c#-4.0

I'd like to ask the honorable society of Stackoverflow if there any ways to configure WCF server to write separate logs for separate endpoints? Either using EntLib or plain WCF.

I think it's possible to do by writing a custom trace listener, but, possibly, other ways exist.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware this is not possible out of the box.

Microsoft Service Trace Viewer does allow you to filter the service log files using XPath expressions. This allows filtering to be done by endpoint or using any other diagnostic data.